# Sticky scroll nav menu

Tags: html, css, fixed, sticky, scrollto

Currently, I'm working on the single webpage and got some issue with the final output which is when clicking the link menu, it does not go to the targeted div position(correct me if I'm wrong). And when clicking again the link, it will go to the other position.

I follow this tutorial, [callmenick](http://callmenick.com/post/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation)

Here is the reproduction of it, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faliqaiman/ju648br4/)

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li> <- when any click link, and then click again, there's some action happen. *bugs?*
    <li><a href="#tech-spec">Tech Spec</a></li>
    <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: To me its not clear what the question is: "when click the link menu" which one? "not goes to the targeted div" it does except for buy but there is no section for it.

Comment: @Type-Style, you can click the 'overview' link, and then click again. there's some action happen there.

Comment: thx. I posted an answer describing the problem in detail. Is that what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to add your missing *Buy* section and in your navigation add `href` to the link, like:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tech-spec">Tech Spec</a></li>
    <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#buy">Buy</a></li> <!-- You are missing your href attribute here -->
  </ul>
</nav>
```

All the rest seems to work fine.

Comment: those buy link will be a popup. can you refresh and click two times the 'overview' link and see the action. sorry if my previous description is not very clear.

Comment: By the action, do you mean scrolling down to the section on the first click, and scrolling little up on the second ?

Answer (score 0):

I see no issue on my machine, but this feature can be approached in a different way. See my example below, this might solve the issue

---

1. Add anchor class
2. Add data attribute
3. Make global function that scrolls to certain point

So for instance

```
<div id="button-name"></div>
```

becomes

```
<div id="button-name" class="scrollAnchor" data-anchor-dest="#section-more-info"></div>
```

Now there is a JavaScript action required, this one reads the *data-anchor-dest* attribute and scrolls to it.

```
$(".scrollAnchor").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    anchorDestination = $(this).data("anchor-dest");
    smoothScrollTo(anchorDestination);
});

function smoothScrollTo(element)
{
    $("html, body").stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

Now the usual question, how compatible is it? [This compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset), I have tested this myself in IE9 and it works.

*This answer may be more of a teardown than a fix, but I hope this helps*

Comment: hi. can you help to reproduce in jsfiddle the tips?

Answer (score 0):

Now I get it,

the Problem is that the **fixed nav** is not part of the **document flow** anymore.
Therefore it won't reserve **height**. Or in other words the rest of the elements don't know its there anymore. Just like `display: none;`

---

You need to find a way to push the elements down by the height of the fixed nav but only if the nav is fixed.

There are a couple ways to to that, but it depends on the layout.
First way that comes to mind is applying `padding-top: ?px`; to the #product-nav, via JS as soon as fixed is applied to the nav.

edit:
https://jsfiddle.net/ju648br4/4/

Comment: hi. can you help to reproduce in jsfiddle the tips?

Comment: i added a js-fiddle link. It's not perfect but it does what I said I would try